# Why is SHA3 prefixed with SHA despite the fact that it is structurally different from SHA2 and SHA1?

Tags: sha-3

Why is SHA-3 prefixed with “SHA” despite the fact that it is structurally different from SHA-2 and SHA-1?

SHA-0, 1 & 2 and MD5 is based on Merkle–Damgård construction, while SHA-3 falls under Sponge functions.

Therefore why SHA-3 is still prefixed with “SHA” despite the fundamental difference in its construction?

Comment: Same reason MacOS is still macOS.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

SHA3 is the name of the hash function *standard*, and the acronym is for 'Secure Hash Algorithm', pretty neutral one saying nothing about the structure.  The algorithm itself was originally named Keccak by the developers.  After winning the SHA3 competition, Keccak *became* SHA3.

Comment: +1: SHA3 is more of a "title" than a "name"

Comment: Note that there were ideas to call SHA-3 AHS or ASH or some other names just to set it appart. Fortunately those didn't make it.

Comment: I wouldn't say that Keccak *became* SHA-3 so much as it was *incorporated* into SHA-3 as its core primitive, in terms of which it defines the four SHA-3 hash functions and the two SHAKE extendable output functions (XOFs).  But that's really just a nitpick.

Answer (score 10):

#### SHA…

This naming was introduced by NIST (see https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Hash-Functions) way back in 1993 during SHA-0 standardization efforts (which ended in SHA-1).

*SHA* stands for ***S***ecure **H**ash **A**lgorithm; while the *-1*, -2*,  and *-3* parts can be regarded as a sort of version number. The higher that number, the more recent the hashing algorithm is.

> Therefore why SHA-3 is still prefixed with “SHA” despite the fundamental difference in its construction?

When it says “Secure Hash Algorithm” on the package, it doesn’t matter what kind of hash algorithm NIST puts in there, as long as it’s secure. That’s why they chose the naming while embracing standardization towards *Federal Information Processing Standards*.

#### A word about MD…

Just to be sure you’re not stepping into a potential pitfall: note that “MD” as used in MD5 does not stand for “Merkle–Damgård”. Instead, it is short for **M**essage **D**igest; again with appended numbers which can be regarded as a kind of version number.

To make it complete, maybe I should also point out that [MD… isn’t a NIST naming thing.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/56467/12164)